Moderator Pro Tem Announcement
Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional moderators. You can read about the program here: Moderators Pro Tempore.
I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that every community’s issues are properly addressed:



We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them and appreciate the hard work and time they will contribute.
Did I overlook anyone?
Almost certainly. There are many members here who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in no way a slight against them. Ideally, moderators should elected by the community, and that's why we'll hold elections once the site graduates.
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Best of luck! May the mod abuse flow and the flag queue stay silent.

Welcome to the team, @Charo!

Thank you! I will try to do my best!

@DenisNardin: Congratulations and welcome to the Mod team!

I was delightfully surprised today to see the diamond next to Charo's nickname!
Tanti auguri di buon lavoro!

Thanks @egreg! I will try to do my best!

@charo, come è avvenuto tutto ciò? Cioè, qual è stata la dinamica dei fatti che hanno determinato questa nomina?

@ElberichSchneider: Questo è spiegato nel messaggio di abby, non penso che ci sia niente di più da dire.

Congratz to the new mods! Huzzah!

Thank you Abby!
I hope we'll able to help this community to grow! :)

I'm sure they'll do a nice job!

Congratulations! ...and good work...
